# What's the number of combinations when randomly picking $n$ balls from a bag with infinite number of balls with 3 colors?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

What's the number of combinations when randomly picking $n$ balls from a bag with infinite number of balls with 3 colors?

Suppose 3 colors are A, B and C. I started with $n=1$ and the answer is 3 (A or B or C). For $n=2$, the answer is also easily derived as 6; there is 1 case ending with A (AA), 2 cases ending with B (AB, BB) and 3 cases ending with C (AC, BC, CC). When $n=3$, it's 10 = 1 (only 1 case ending with A for $n=2$) + 3 (cases ending with A or B for $n=2$) + 6 (all possible cases for $n=2$). So I could do the calculation recursively, but what's the general formula for $f(n)$ would look like?

Thank you!

Comment: See [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#:~:text=In%20the%20context%20of%20combinatorial,his%20classic%20book%20on%20probability.)

Comment: Thank you but how does this applies to the problem?

Comment: If you have $n$ choices from  $k$ colors, then an unordered selection is given by an ordered $k-$tuple of non-negative integers which sum to $n$ so...

Comment: Thank you I think I understand it now. It's like Theorem 2 in the link you posted. The bar separates different colors. So it's basically like $2$ out of $n+2$.

Comment: It is exactly the same as Theorem $2$ from that link.  With $n$ balls and $k$ colors you get $\binom {n+k-1}{k-1}$ possibilities.  In your case, $k=3$ so, yes.  $\binom {n+2}{2}$, or $\frac {(n+2)(n+1)}2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be seen as one of combination with replacement. More in particular, infinitely many balls of 3 colors are like 3 balls of different colors with replacement (since at each step you can always pick one of the 3 colored balls). Moreover, here, we are not interested in the order. Therefore, we can use the following formula:
$$
\frac{(n+r-1)!}{n!(r-1)!}
$$
where $r$ is the number of distinct balls (3 in our case) and $n$ is the number of balls that we pick from the bag.

Comment: Thank you for replying but For $n=3$, what is $r$?

Comment: I've just changed the notation to make it coherent with the question, sorry. Hopefully this makes it a little bit clearer.

Comment: Thank you! The Stars and Bars method mentioned in the question comments is also interesting and intuitive approach. You can consider add more details about that approach as well.